# How to position an element using "fixed" relative to the scroll position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicking on a div, I need to re-position the current element so that it sticks to the top of the viewport/window, but taking the current scroll position in consideration. When using just plain css `position: fixed;` I'm well aware of the fact that the scroll position does not matter - the element will go out of bounds and get invisible. How can I achieve this behavior? I suppose it should be done using JS.

Current Code:

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')];

if(elements.length) {
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      el.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  gap: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr) );
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: position sticky?

Comment: Nope, wont work.